# Concatenate dataframes in Pandas using an iteration but it doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes indexed more or less by the same MultiIndex (a few values may be missing on each dataframe, but the total rows exceeds 70K and the missing values is always less than 10). I want to attach/merge/concatenate to all of them a given dataframe (with same indexation). I tried doing this using a for iteration with a tuple, as in the example here. However, at the end, all my data frames do not merge. I provide a simple example where this happens. Why they do not merge?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), index = ["A", "B", "C", "D"], columns = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd"])
df2 = df1 + 2
df3 = df1 - 2
for df in (df1, df2):
    df = pd.merge(df, df3, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = "inner")
df1, df2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your expected result?

In the `for` loop, `df` is the loop variable and also the result on the left-hand side of the assignment statement.  Here is the same loop with print statements to provide additional information.  I think you are over-writing intermediate results.

```
for df in (df1, df2):
    print(df)
    print('-----')
    df = pd.merge(df, df3, left_index = True, right_index = True, how = "inner")
    print(df)
    print('==========', end='\n\n')
print(df)
```

You could combine df1, df2 and df3 like this.

```
print(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1))

   1st  2nd  3rd  1st  2nd  3rd  1st  2nd  3rd
A    0    1    2    2    3    4   -2   -1    0
B    3    4    5    5    6    7    1    2    3
C    6    7    8    8    9   10    4    5    6
D    9   10   11   11   12   13    7    8    9
```

UPDATE

Here is an idiomatic way to import and concatenate several CSV files, possibly in multiple directories.  In short:  read each file into a separate data frame; add each data frame to a list; concatenate once at the end.

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/cookbook.html#reading-multiple-files-to-create-a-single-dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

df = list()

for filename in Path.cwd().rglob('*.csv'):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as handle:
        t = pd.read_csv(handle)
        df.append(t)
        print(filename.name, t.shape)
df = pd.concat(df)
print('\nfinal: ', df.shape)

penny.csv (62, 8)
penny-2020-06-24.csv (144, 9)
...etc

final:  (474, 20)
```

Comment: I have dozens of data frames (say df1, ...., dfn) and I want to add to each one of them a single dataframe (dfUnique, say). I don't want to do copy-paste of code but a for-loop or other similar iteration to do this for me. The code I write, if you run it, after having run it, df1 and df2 remain the same (df3 has not been merged).

Comment: The link you posted gave the solution I wanted.